# Pass boolean value in shortcode

Tags: shortcode, customization

In WordPress shortcodes, how can I pass boolean attributes?
Both of `[shortcode boolean_attribute="true"]` or `[shortcode boolean_attribute=true]` are giving string values.

EDIT

There would be no problem for users who know what they're doing if I use the trick which was commented by @brasofilo. But some users will get lost if they give an attribute `false` value and receive `true` value. So is there any other solution?

Comment: Simply don't pass the attribute and you'll have `false`, otherwise `true`.

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo. But is there any other solution? I think some users will get lost if they give an attribute "false" value, but they will get "true" value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is easy to use `0` and `1` values and then typecasting inside the function:

`[shortcode boolean_attribute='1']` or `[shortcode boolean_attribute='0']`

but if you want you can also strictly check for `'false'` and assign it to boolean, in this way you can also use:

`[shortcode boolean_attribute='false']` or `[shortcode boolean_attribute='true']`

Then:

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'shortcode_cb' );

function shortcode_cb( $atts ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'boolean_attribute' => 1
  ), $atts ) );
  if ( $boolean_attribute === 'false' ) $boolean_attribute = false; // just to be sure...
  $boolean_attribute = (bool) $boolean_attribute;
}
```

Comment: [Do not use `extract()`.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99604/73) :)

Comment: That's great answer. But I thought it would be great if users had true or false choice. Sorry I cannot accept your answer as accepted.

Comment: @SodbilegGansukh this code works also with `'true'` and `'false'`

Comment: @toscho I just copied and pasted from [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Examples) ;)

Comment: @SodbilegGansukh All arguments are passed as strings, because they can be entered (typed) as strings only. There is no other way than this answer. Try to type a stringless boolean value …

Comment: `wp_validate_boolean()` function in WordPress 4.0.0 or above is helpful in validating boolean values. Function Reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_boolean/

Answer (score 33):

As an extension to @G.M. answer (which is the only possible way to do this), here's a slightly shortened/beautified and and an extended version (which I personally prefer):

### Shortened/Beautified variant

It's enough to do a `boolean` check for the contained value. If it's `true`, the result will be `(bool) true`, else it will be false. This produces a one case `true`, everything else `false` result.

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcodeWPSE', 'wpse119294ShortcodeCbA' );
function wpse119294ShortcodeCbA( $atts ) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'boolAttr' => 'true'
    ), $atts, 'shortcodeWPSE' );

    $args['boolAttr'] = 'true' === $args['boolAttr'];
}
```

### Extended/User-safe variant

The reason why I prefer this version is that it allows the user to type in `on/yes/1` as an alias for `true`. This reduces the chance for user errors when the user doesn't remember what the actual value for `true` was.

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcodeWPSE', 'wpse119294ShortcodeCbA' );
function wpse119294ShortcodeCbA( $atts ) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'boolAttr' => 'true'
    ), $atts, 'shortcodeWPSE' );

    $args['boolAttr'] = filter_var( $args['boolAttr'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );
}
```

#### Additional notes:

1) Always pass the 3rd argument for `shortcode_atts()`. Else the shortcode attributes filter is impossible to target.

```
// The var in the filter name refers to the 3rd argument.
apply_filters( "shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}", $out, $pairs, $atts );
```

2) Never use `extract()`. Even core wants to reduce those calls. It's equally worse to `global` variables, as IDEs don't stand a chance to resolve the extracted contents and will throw failure messages.

Comment: Wow, that's a great answer. Thank you so much. I wish I had enough reputation to vote up for your answer. And thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: I voted on your behalf, Sodbileg. :)

Comment: `wp_validate_boolean()` function in WordPress 4.0.0 or above is helpful in validating boolean values. Function Reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_boolean/

Comment: @AamerShahzad This is a (imho unnecessarily added) alternative to `filter_var( $var, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ).`, what even the docblock of this function itself states.

Comment: @kaiser this is just for the information.

Comment: @AamerShahzad understood. no problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Here a shorter simple version, building on gmazzap's answer:**

Use '1' or '0', then cast using a double bang "!!" which changes a "truthy/falsey" value to it's boolean equivalent

note this will NOT work with "true" and "false" strings, only "1" and "0"

```
[myshortcode myvar="0"]

myshortcodefunction( $args )
{
   $myvar = !! $args['myvar'];
   var_dump($myvar); // prints bool(false)
}
```