# PHPStorm variable warnings

Tags: ide

I code in PHPStorm and include wp-admin and wp-include in my path, but get code inspection warnings related to undefined / unused variables.

Should I be concerned about these?  How would I go about satisfying a resolution to resolve the error (without just turning inspection off)

[image]

Comment: The value of the var comes from the user so can I just define var = null before extract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are using `extract()`, and PHPStorm cannot know where the variable is coming from. [Do not use `extract()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99604/73). Ever.

It was [removed from almost all WordPress functions](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22400), and so should you do.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use it, you can add a comments before your variable like this:

```
/** @var $number integer */
```

It will prevent a warnings in PHPStorm.