# Echo title with permalink

Tags: permalinks, widgets, title

[image]

I was creating a wordpress sidebar widget that will display recent posts. For, this i've created a custom widget(**popular_posts_widget.php**) and included in my theme **functions.php**. I was trying to display post titles which when clicked display respective posts associated with it. But, unfortunately link doesn't work. How can i fix this??

This is my **functions.php**

```
<?php 

/****************************************************/
/* Define Constants */   
/***************************************************/

define ('THEMEROOT', get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
define ('IMAGES', THEMEROOT . '/img' );
define ('FONTS', THEMEROOT . '/fonts' );
define ('JS', THEMEROOT . '/js' );

/****************************************************/
/* Menus */  
/***************************************************/

function register_my_menus() {
         register_nav_menus(array(

         'main-menu'=> __('Main Menu')
         ));
}
add_action('init' , 'register_my_menus');

if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) {

    register_sidebar(
    array(
         'name' => __('Main Sidebar'),
         'id' => 'main-sidebar',
         'description' => __('The main sidebar area'),
         'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
         'after_widget' => '</div>',
         'before_title' => '<h2>',
         'after_title' => '</h2>'
   ));

}

/****************************************************/
/* Add Theme Support for post thumbnail */  
/***************************************************/

if(function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
   add_theme_support('post-formats', array('link', 'quote', 'gallery'));
   add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post'));
}

/****************************************************/
/* Load Custom Widgets */  
/***************************************************/

require_once('functions/widget-ad-260.php');
require_once('functions/popular-posts-widget.php');
require_once('functions/rh_about.php');
require_once('functions/rh_tags.php');

 ?>
```

This is my **popular-posts-widget.php**

```
<?php 

/****************************************************/
/* Widget that displays a popular posts widget */  
/***************************************************/

class Popular extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        $params = array(
            'name' => 'Creative : Popular Posts Widget',
            'description' => 'Displays recent posts of your blog'
            );
        parent:: __construct('Popular','',$params);
    }

    public function form($instance) {
        //display our form in widget page
        extract($instance);
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?>">Title : </label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title') ?>" 
            value="<?php if(isset($title)) echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    public function widget($args,$instance) {
        //displays our widget
        extract($args);
        extract($instance);
        echo $before_widget;
           echo $before_title .$title. $after_title;
           echo '<div class="popular">';
           if(have_posts()) {
            while (have_posts()) {
                the_post();
                echo "<ul>";
                echo "<li>";
                $link = the_permalink();
                echo "<a href=$link>";
                echo the_title();
                echo "</a>";
                echo "<p>";
                echo the_time(get_option('date_format'));
                echo "</p>";
                echo "</li>";
                echo "</ul>";
            }
           }
           else {
            echo "<h1>No posts were found!</h1>";
           }
           echo '</div>';
        echo $after_widget;
    }
} 

add_action('widgets_init','rh_register_popular');
function rh_register_popular() {
    register_widget('Popular');
}

 ?>
```

You can also check preview listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
$link = the_permalink();
```

Replace it with:

```
$link = get_permalink();
```

Notice that the WordPress `the_*` functions will *echo* the output, but `get_*` will *return* it. But of course there are exceptions to this rule ;-) So you don't need this:

```
echo the_title();
```

Just use this instead:

```
the_title();
```

or the [usage example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/168971/26350) given by @PieterGoosen.

Don't use `extract()` as it's bad for debugging and deprecated in the core. See for example this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99604/26350) by @toscho.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer from @birgire, you can also just use [`the_title( $before, $after, $echo );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) in the following matter to get the same result

```
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
```