# Check if CTP category taxonomy is set in shortcode

Tags: shortcode, query, conditional-tags, customization

I have created a custom post type with the ability to add categories (taxonomy).

Taxonomy

```
function create_cat_tax() {
        register_taxonomy(
        'cpt_cats',
        'cpt_faqs',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'FAQ Categories',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New FAQ category',
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
        );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_cat_tax', 0 );
```

I have also created the ability to add all the custom post type's content using a shortcode.

Shortcode code:

```
function cpt_sc($atts) {

extract(shortcode_atts( array(
  'posts' => -1,
  'order' => '',
  'orderby' => '',
  'title' => '',
  'id' => '',
  'category' => ''
), $atts ) );

$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => $posts,
      'order' => $order,
      'orderby' => $orderby,
      'post_type' => 'cpt_faqs',
      'p' => $id,
      'cpt_cats' => $category
    ); 

}
add_shortcode( 'faqs', 'cpt_sc' );
```

How can I query to see if a category has been set in the shortcode?

e.g `[faqs category="category one"]`

Previously I've used the below  and works with no problem.

```
if ( 'true' == $atts['accordion'] )
{
    ob_start();
    echo 'content here';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
else
{
    ob_start();
    echo 'other content here';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please correct your mark-up

Comment: Don't use extract, was explained [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99604/18731) by @toscho and [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#dont-extract) by WP. Your $args not return too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm in the process of updating the above code but have his a stumbling block regarding adding categories as an attribute. Can you possibly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in comments, [do not ever use `extract()`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#dont-extract). It's use was removed from core a few years ago. The codex was also cleaned up. The use of `extract()` is even discouraged in PHP. You can rewrite your attributes as follow: (***NOTE:*** Requires PHP 5.4+)

```
$attributes = shortcode_atts( 
    [
        'posts'    => -1,
        'order'    => '',
        'orderby'  => '',
        'title'    => '',
        'id'       => '',
        'category' => ''
    ],
    $atts 
);
```

To access an attribute, you can use the following syntax (*which is normal array syntax*)

```
$attribute['category']
```

If you are going to make use of the `'taxonomy' => 'term'` syntax, you need to make sure your term is passed a slug. Also, when you [register your taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), you need to make sure that the `query_var` argument is left at default. I would rather suggest in using a proper `tax_query` which is more flexible.

In the example below, I have set a `field` attribute which is set to `slug` by default. This means that `category` can be a string or an array of slugs. If you need to pass term ID's as an integer, string or an array, you can just pass `term_id` as value to the `field` attribute

```
add_shortcode( 'faqs', 'cpt_sc' );
function cpt_sc($atts) {

    $attributes = shortcode_atts( 
        [
            'posts'    => -1,
            'order'    => '',
            'orderby'  => '',
            'title'    => '',
            'id'       => '',
            'category' => ''
            'field'    => 'slug'
        ],
        $atts 
    );

    // Set up your variables
    $posts    = $attribute['posts'];
    $order    = $attribute['order'];
    $orderby  = $attribute['orderby'];
    $id       = $attribute['id'];
    $category = $attribute['category'];
    $field    = $attribute['field'];

    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'cpt_faqs',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'order'          => $order,
        'orderby'        => $orderby,
        'p'              => $id,
        'tax_query'      => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'cpt_cats',
                'field'    => $field,
                'terms'    => $category
            ]
        ]
    ]; 

    // Rest of your shortcode

}
```

### FEW NOTES

- The code needs at least PHP 5.4. You should however be on PHP 5.6 already to be safe
- To make the code more dynamic, you can always set attributes for the post type and taxonomy
- It is always advice-able to escape, sanitize and/or validate any user passed data according to the data type expected. Because you are passing all attributes directly to `WP_Query`, you should be save if you do not sanitize/escape/validate as `WP_Query` will take care of that before the SQL query is executed. Still, it is good and recommended to always escape, sanitize and/or validate

### EDIT

I actually forgot the handle how to check if a term is passed. You can check if a term is passed, and if the value is empty, you can simply bail or return an error message

Check with attribute

```
if ( '' == $attribute['category'] )
    return;
```

Check when the variables is set

```
if ( '' == $category )
    return;
```

### EDIT - From comments

> If a category is not specified in the shortcode, no results are returned. How can I make all posts return if no categroy is set?

We can display all posts regardless if no term is set by conditionally adding our `tax_query`. If a term is passed, add the `tax_query`, else, do not append the `tax_query`

We can try the following

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'cpt_faqs',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts,
    'order'          => $order,
    'orderby'        => $orderby,
    'p'              => $id,
];

if ( $category ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'cpt_cats',
            'field'    => $field,
            'terms'    => $category
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: This works thank you so much.
I have one small issue. If a category is not specified in the shortcode, no results are returned. How can I make all posts return if no categroy is set?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Pieter Goosen - Thank you so much for your help. Works perfectly.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked out for you. Enjoy ;-)